# JUnitEE vs JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-ee, junit

I know what unit testing is in general and what *JUnit* is in particular. But [here](http://www.junitee.org/index.html) I see that there is a project called *JUnitEE* which seems to me to be a wrapper over JUnit. So I would like to better understand the pain point of using vanilla *JUnit* and how *JUnitEE* is able to solve those problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not so much a wrapper or replacement for JUnit, but an extension of JUnit to allow running tests on a J2EE app server. There are many similar projects, such as HTTPUnit for testing web application UIs and DBUnit for making Database fixtures easier.

But JunitEE hasn't been updated in almost 10 years, so I doubt it's very useful for (or even compatible with) modern Java EE applications.

Comment: But why JUnit can not be runn on J2EE app servers..After all it is all Java or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: @Geek: The standard JUnit TestRunners are just not designed to run in an app server environment. The "Why JUnitEE?" section on the project page explains this. But note that nowadays a different model is common: running the tests completely outside an app server. This has become possible with Java EE 5, since EJB implementation classes can be POJOs.

Comment: We are using JUnitEE at work, with JAVA 8&11 and JBoss EAP 7. It works like charm. I give you that the repo has not been updated for more than 10 years and you will not much documents out there. The only documentation is on sourceforge and no maven central repo exposed as well. I have worked with both ANT and MAVEN task, its just native java code in junitee which will work irrespective of server version.